# Upload artifact with tag other than "latest" to Artifactory NPM repo

Tags: npm, artifactory

I'm using [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) to upload tarballs to Artifactory NPM repository:

```
curl -X PUT \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
 -T path-to-tarball.tgz \
 "http://<server>/artifactory/<repo>/<scope>/<package>/<package>-<version>.tgz"
```

It works, but it looks like the recently uploaded artifact is always marked as `latest` when you query this repository. Usually it's fine, but not always.

I tried to use [URL Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution) by appending `;tag=other` to the target URL, but with no luck.

Anybody managed to tag NPM versions uploaded to Artifactory via REST API?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you cannot manage NPM tags in Artifactory through the REST API.

There is a default handling for the `latest` tag, and it can be handled in one of the two modes - either by semantic version (the highest published version is marked as latest) or by publishing time (the most recently uploaded package is marked as latest). This setting is system-wide, so you cannot change it per repository. [Source](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#npmRegistry-SpecifyingtheLatestVersion)

On top of that, you can use `npm dist-tags` CLI command ([reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag)) with custom `--registry` that points to your Artifactory repository to manage tags on the packages that you upload. Note that it must point to the real ("local") repo and not to the virtual repository.